# In SitePrism Capybara framework, why we create an object using @ symbol?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, site-prism

I am just trying to find out why i need to define it as instance variable? Why not local? I know @home can be shared across all step def methods. Without this is there any other specific reason? Please help me out to understand the reason other than what i know.

```
When /^I navigate to the google home page$/ do
  @home = Home.new
  @home.load
end
```

Here's the link URL: https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism

Answer (score 1):

The only reason is for sharing between steps.  If the object is only needed in the one step then it can be a local variable.  If @home is not used in any other step your example could just become

```
When /^I navigate to the google home page$/ do
  Home.new.load
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are used in the examples in SitePrism as instance variables is because that example uses Cucumber and all instance variables are accessible in the single World context.